# Jquery alert does not display the expected code

Tags: jquery, html

I don't know whats wrong with my jQuery code. A better explanation on what is happening on my code would help a lot.

When the append is called it displayed the elements I expected to see but on my alert I can only see 1 word 'first'.

#### HTML

```
<div id="myDiv">

</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="append"/>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    var myElement = '<span id="spn1">first </span><span id="spn2">second </span><span id="spn3">third </span><span id="spn4">fourth </span>';

    var $val = $(myElement).not('#spn2');

    $('#myDiv').append($val);
    alert($val.html());

});
```

Or the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MCvLQ/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok let me explain this to you line by line.
First,

```
var $val = $(myElement).not('#spn2')
```

this says that you are selecting all elements on myElement excluding the element having the id of spn2.

```
$val now is equivalent to
--------------------------
<span id="spn1">first </span>
<span id="spn3">third </span>
<span id="spn4">fourth </span>
```

the elements above as you notice, the element with the id 'spn2' is no longer there. Basically **.not() selector** is defined as to **Remove elements from the set of matched elements.**

then next this statement

```
$('#myDiv').append();
```

adds all the elements of $val to the end part of the myDiv.

I added a predefined element inside myDiv so you will notice that all the elements are added at the last portion of the div. 
I also created a button for you to see the reverse of **.append()** which is **.prepend()**. This will also add the elements on top of the existing elements inside the myDiv.

See my the revised code here to see the difference http://jsfiddle.net/MCvLQ/1/

Lastly

```
alert($val.html());
```

**.html()** is defined as, to **Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements.**
Refer here
http://api.jquery.com/html/

Notice on the latest value of $val, as you can see the first element is 'first ' so that explains why your alert displays only the word 'first'. **.html()** method uses the browser's innerHTML property.

***Additional Info:***

Aside from **.not() selector** you can also use **:not() selector**. Refer here http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

For speed issues, this test http://jsperf.com/jquery-css3-not-vs-not says that **:not()** is way much better than **.not()** on most of the browsers except IE8.

But, still that depends on you. Whichever is more readable for you. Codewise **.not()** is easier to read at a first glance of the code.

Comment: I see :) Thanks a lot. No wonder I only get the 'first' as the result. Now it's clear to me. Thank you so much sir!